# Why is this filter routine so slow?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui-list

I'm using CoreData for the first time in my app, and when I filter my data it take 20-30 seconds for it to filter. The list view has a floating button that when tapped lets the user choose what state they want to filter by. Tapping this will return to the list view and it will appear frozen while it processes. The data it returns is accurate, it just seems to take far longer than it should. At most there are 3600 entries, so this should be immediate.

This is the code that populates my filtered list view.

```
init(categoryFilter: String, stateFilter: String) {
  if (categoryFilter.count > 0 && stateFilter.count > 0){
       let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category BEGINSWITH %@ AND state BEGINSWITH %@", categoryFilter, stateFilter)
       fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Bonus>(entity: Bonus.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: predicate)
   } else if (categoryFilter.count > 0 && stateFilter.count <= 0){
       let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category BEGINSWITH %@", categoryFilter)
       fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Bonus>(entity: Bonus.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: predicate)
   } else if (categoryFilter.count <= 0 && stateFilter.count > 0){
       let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "state BEGINSWITH %@", stateFilter)
       fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Bonus>(entity: Bonus.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: predicate)
   } else {
       fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Bonus>(entity: Bonus.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
   }
```

I'm not sure what other code will be useful to you, but let me know what else I should post.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use Instruments to check that the time is indeed spent on the query and not somewhere else?

Comment: Since the user is selecting a specific state then why use BEGINSWITH, use == instead. Maybe the same can be done for category?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried using == instead, it didn't help at all.

Comment: @Sweeper It looks like you might be onto something. The query seems to be executing quickly and runs on a background thread, but the main thread is hitting 100% CPU for 15 seconds anytime I set or clear a filter.